# Hyphenation controls beyond \lefthyphenmin \righthyphenmin

Tags: hyphenation

Seeking pointers to additional hyphenation controls under LuaLaTeX with `microtype`. Typography books (e.g., Bringhurst’s *The Elements of Typographic Style* and Argentsinger’s *A Grammar of Typography*) recommend a number of hyphenation rules:

- Minimum word length for hyphenation (6 per Argentsinger)
- Not hyphenating the last word in a paragraph (both)
- Maximum consecutive hyphenation (both recommend 3)
- Not hyphenating acronyms
- Adjusting the width of the “hyphenation zone”
- Adjusting the tradeoff between better spacing and fewer hyphens (an InDesign setting, apparently)

Both authors would, for example, have us set `\lefthyphenmin2` and `\righthyphenmin3` (in English). I understand `\hyphenpenalty=####`, `\emergencystretch`, and `\tolerance` can dial hyphenation up and down. Overall, I am seeking guidance to better hyphenation, but specifically:

**Are there LaTeX settings to control the bulleted factors directly?** Or, should I just delegate to the hyphenation engine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Minimum word length for hyphenation (6 per Argentsinger)

  `\hyphenationmin=6`
- Not hyphenating the last word in a paragraph (both)

  You could use a lua callback to box the last word before hyphenation
- Maximum consecutive hyphenation (both recommend 3)

  Not directly but you can set `\doublehyphendemerits` to discourage (or ban) adjacent pairs of hyphenated lines.
- Not hyphenating acronyms

  make your acronym macro box the acronym
- Adjusting the width of the “hyphenation zone”

  Not sure what you mean, but perhaps configure protrusion for `-` character using microtype
- Adjusting the tradeoff between better spacing and fewer hyphens (an InDesign setting, apparently)

  That is the basic mechanism of TeX's line breaker doing a least cost optimisation for linebreaking a paragraph so balancing the penalties (and demerits which are penalties squared) from stretching white space and adding hyphens.